# Sweet alert confirm delete on PHP app is not working

Tags: sweetalert2

In my PHP app its normally deleted when click on the link/button

but when I implement sweet alert its not working or it just return false. I am using `sweetalert2`

Here is my button code

```
<a href="http://localhost/app/pages-role-list.php?delete_role=18" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-confirm">delete</a>
```

My sweet init

```
$('.delete-confirm').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = $(this).attr('href');


    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Delete'

    },function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
            return true;
            window.location.href = url;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I see you edited your question. What exactly is the behaviour now. When you click on the a tag, does the popup open? If so, what happens when you click on the "Delete" button?

Comment: In your edit, you are returning true before redirecting so the redirect never executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback was not using correct syntax..

Here is the working code:

```
$('.delete-confirm').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const url = $(this).attr('href');

            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: 'question',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Delete'
                
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    window.location.href = url;
                } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: I have updated my code actually `href` has a variable value 18 in `delete_role=18`  So I I cannot use direct link have updated my code

Comment: You are returning true before redirecting :)

Comment: The code to redirect never runs. Swap these two around `return true;` and `window.location.href = url;`

Comment: What exactly is happening? Does it actually redirect or not? Does the sweet alert popup trigger initially?

Comment: sweet alert pop but not redirect after click delete

Comment: It appears sweetalerts callbacks are only triggered on a confirm. You do not need to check an "isConfirm"

Comment: I have solved this and its now working. I have edited your and answer and added my code

Comment: Great, So it was the callback syntax. Good to know I was along the right lines!